# Undoing changelist in P4Python

Tags: python-3.x, p4python

I have an issue with undoing changes in Perforce using p4python given that I have sumitted the changelist that I now want to undo.
My idea is first to create a changelist and then run the undo. However, Iam doing something wrong and the file doesnt get undone.

```
# new_cl is the created changelist
# cl_to_undo is the changelist to undo.
# description is string
P4.run("undo", '-c'+new_cl, filePath+"@" + cl_to_undo, description)

# Submit
P4.submit(new_cl)
```

Would appriciate any help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

The `undo` command doesn't take a `description` argument.

```
C:\Perforce\test>p4 help undo

    undo -- Undo a range of revisions

    p4 undo [-n] [-c changelist#] file[revRange]
```

You should set the `Description` field of `new_cl` at the time you create it (presumably you have some code earlier in your script that creates a pending changelist with `p4.get_change` and `p4.save_change`, and it sets a description -- put your `description` text in there).